# Which init system is main on particular system?

Tags: systemd, upstart, init

I have installed application with several init scripts as for `dpkg -L application` shows. For example:

```
/etc/init/application.conf
/etc/init.d/application
/usr/systemd/applaication.service
```

But i use just `service application start` for start? How determine which script should be used for start application?

As i know on Ubuntu 12.04 use upstart by default so it is `/etc/init/application.conf` script but when i do `update-rc.d` it create symlink for `/etc/rc*.d` dir to `/etc/init.d/application` so it use SysV init script instead upstart while upstart is default init in Ubuntu. I am confused.

Comment: Well the first 2 things are not scripts as they end with .conf suffix I guess. So it gives you only only one, you can open it, it's a systemd service file.

Comment: Upstart as i know use init scripts with conf, but in init.d my fault there was application, just, without .conf.

Comment: I have opened each of them, but they looks like init script, not config like in /etc/default.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but you can know which init system it is using by checking what does /sbin/init points to with `ls -l /sbin/init`. Once you known which init system you are using, you will use systemctl, service or update-rc.d to enable a specific service.